# Design-pattern to use to access similar objects with different field names

Tags: java, design-patterns, polymorphism, gson

What design-pattern, if any, would be most appropriate in this situation.

```
public class PersonFromDB1 {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String Car;
}

public class PersonFromDB2 {
  private String first_name;
  private String last_name;
  private String boat;
}
```

Out of these two person types, the only data I would like to work on is fist name and last name regardless of how it field name is name inside the different DBs. firstName and first_name represents the same - name of a person/customer - so does lastName and last-name. The car and boat fields are, in my example, completely irrelevant and should therefore be ignored.

Using, maybe polymorphism or the adapter pattern (?), I would like to create a list of objects that includes persons from DB1 and DB2 under the same type - of PersonInOurDB.

In the end, my goal is to be able to call GSON serialization/desarialization on myClass alone.

```
public class PersonInOurDB {
  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;
}
```

Comment: A_1 and B_1 are equivalent? What do you mean by that? Since they are in the same class how does that help? Did you maybe mean A_1 and A_2? Also field D is not present in your example (I assume you mean field E). Can you give an example of what you mean by the merge of TypeA and TypeB? I can guess, but it's hard to really judge.

Comment: Do you want both objects (TypeA and TypeB) to look equal when serialized to json? E.g. `{"A":"StringValue","B":"StringValue"}`

Comment: SirRichie and René, my bad. I clarified my small example.

Comment: Exactly, i want these to be equal, so to have gson work on these in one go

Answer (score 0):

A simple selection based on the type is all you really need. This could be considered a builder pattern because it just initializes a new instance of myClass.

Note, this is rough pseudo code.

```
FunctionName(SomeType instance)
{
  string aPostfix = "_1";
  string bPostfix = "_2";

  string selectedPostFix;

// This is your strategy selector
  switch(typeof(SomeType.Name)
  {
    case "TypeA":
      selectedPostFix = aPostFix;
    case "TypeB":
      selectedPostFix = bPostFix;
  } 

  return new myClass()
  {
    A = instance.GetProperty("A" + selectedPostfix).Value,
    B = instance.GetProperty("B" + selectedPostfix).Value,
    ...

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a common access api in java for both objects, then introduce an interface and let both implement it.

If you only want both objects (`PersonFromDB1` and `PersonFromDB2`) to be serialized in the same way by json you can either:

- use annotations - the `@SerializedName` annotation in combination with `@Expose`.
- use the `FieldNamingStratgy` and `ExclusionStrategy`

**Use annotations to control the serialization**

```
public class PersonFromDB1 {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("lastName")
    private String lastName;

    private String car;
}

public class PersonFromDB2 {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("firstName")
    private String first_Name;

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("lastName")
    private String last_Name;

    private String boat;
}
```

Then you can use the `GsonBuilder`

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
PersonFromDB1 person1 = ...; // get the object
PersonFromDB2 person2 = ...; // get the object

System.out.println(gson.toJson(person1));
System.out.println(gson.toJson(person2));
```

**Use `FieldNamingStratgy` and `ExclusionStrategy` to control the serialization**

If you don't want to modify the db objects (you can't or you don't want to add annotations) than there is another way. You can use a `FieldNamingStratgy` and `ExclusionStrategy`.

```
class PersonFromDBNamingStrategy implements FieldNamingStrategy {

    Map<String, String> fieldMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public PersonFromDBNamingStrategy() {
        fieldMapping.put("first_Name", "firstName");
        fieldMapping.put("last_Name", "lastName");
    }

    @Override
    public String translateName(Field f) {
        String name = f.getName();
        if(fieldMapping.contains(name)){
             return fieldMapping.get(name);
        }
        return name;    
    }
}
```

and the `ExclusionStrategy`

```
class PersonFromDExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {

    List<String> validNames = Arrays.asList("car", "boat");

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        String name = f.getName();
        return !validNames.contains(name);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

after that just create Gson like this:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
sonBuilder.addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new PersonFromDExclusionStrategy());
gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingStrategy(new PersonFromDBNamingStrategy());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

PersonFromDB1 person1 = ...; // get the object
PersonFromDB2 person2 = ...; // get the object

System.out.println(gson.toJson(person1));
System.out.println(gson.toJson(person2));
```